# "Contribution" correct Usage

Tags: idioms

What is the correct idiom?

1) His contributions to the field of medicine?

2) His contributions in the field of medicine?

Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

*contributions to* refers to contributions that affected the field of medicine. This is what you would normally use to describe medical researchers.

*contributions in* refers to contributions that involve medicine, but didn't affect the field itself significantly. For instance, a doctor treating their patients, but not making any new discoveries, makes contributions to the patients' lives within the medical profession.